# Oracle 11g ExtractValue to return all XML data

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

I have the following formatted XML produced using Oracle "pivot XML", i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PivotSet>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">1</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc1</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">11</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">22</column>
   </item>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">2</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc2</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">33</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">44</column>
   </item>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">3</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc3</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">55</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">66</column>
   </item>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">4</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc4</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">77</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">882</column>
   </item>
</PivotSet>
```

Based on the above XML, using Oracle SQL (11g) how can I extract all the values above?

As an example, I've been using the following, i.e.

```
select 
        extractvalue(aggregated_interface_no_xml,'/PivotSet/item[2]/column[1]') aa,
        extractvalue(aggregated_interface_no_xml,'/PivotSet/item[2]/column[2]') bb,   
        extractvalue(aggregated_interface_no_xml,'/PivotSet/item[2]/column[3]') cc,
        extractvalue(aggregated_interface_no_xml,'/PivotSet/item[2]/column[4]') dd
from t
```

but this will only return the data relating to INTERFACE_NO 2.

I'm unsure how to pass a wildcard against `/PivotSet/item` to return all records within XML PivotSet, for each item?

Answer (score 1):

Xmlsequence is deprecated. Xmltable is good and clean method.

```
select * from 
xmltable('PivotSet/item' passing 
xmltype('<PivotSet>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">1</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc1</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">11</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">22</column>
   </item>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">2</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc2</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">33</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">44</column>
   </item>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">3</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc3</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">55</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">66</column>
   </item>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">4</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc4</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">77</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">882</column>
   </item>
</PivotSet>')
columns
  row_num  FOR ORDINALITY
  ,aa  varchar2(100) path './column[1]'
  ,bb  varchar2(100) path './column[2]'
  ,cc  varchar2(100) path './column[3]'
  ,dd  varchar2(100) path './column[4]'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an xml table. Something like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(xml_list), '//column[1]') AS interface_no
      ,EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(xml_list), '//column[2]') AS interface_name_a
      ,EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(xml_list), '//column[3]') AS interface_l
      ,EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(xml_list), '//column[4]') AS interface_r
  FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLType('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PivotSet>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">1</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc1</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">11</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">22</column>
   </item>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">2</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc2</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">33</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">44</column>
   </item>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">3</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc3</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">55</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">66</column>
   </item>
   <item>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NO">4</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_NAME_A">abc4</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_L">77</column>
      <column name="INTERFACE_R">882</column>
   </item>
</PivotSet>'), 'PivotSet/item'))) xml_list;
```